# webscraping and extracting dates

Tags: python

Using python BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to extract the date of each newspaper article from a google search page:
https://www.google.com/search?q=citi+group&tbm=nws&ei=u9_1WsetC67l5gKRt7qYBA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1600&bih=794&dpr=1

Here is the my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

article_link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=citi+group&tbm=nws&ei=u9_1WsetC67l5gKRt7qYBA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1600&bih=794&dpr=1"

page = requests.get(article_link)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'slp'}):
    date = links.get_text()
    print(date)
```

The source code is something like:

[image]

The output is  **"PE Hub (blog) - 1 day ago"**

Can I just extract the date part (2018. 5. 11)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why BeautifulSoup is pulling it that way but you can use regex and datetime to clean what you're pulling then you can clean it and use `timedelta` otherwise use `strptime` to convert it to the correct format.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

hold = []
article_link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=citi+group&tbm=nws&ei=u
 9_1WsetC67l5gKRt7qYBA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1600&bih=794&dpr=1"

page = requests.get(article_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'slp'}):
     date = links.get_text()
     hold.append(date) #added list append

---------

#converting to datetime values
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt
hold2 = []
for item in hold:
     item  = re.sub('^.+ - ','', item)
     if 'ago' in item:
         item = re.sub(' days? ago$','',item)
         hold2.append(dt.today() - timedelta(int(item)))
     else:
         item = dt.strptime(item, '%b %d, %Y')
         hold2.append(item)

hold2
[datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 12, 14, 37, 39, 653618),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 8, 14, 37, 39, 653636),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 11, 14, 37, 39, 653643),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 12, 14, 37, 39, 653649),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 8, 14, 37, 39, 653655),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 12, 14, 37, 39, 653661),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 12, 14, 37, 39, 653667),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 8, 14, 37, 39, 653716),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 25, 0, 0)]
```